# Javascript Form Submitting - Anchor vs Button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is there any reason that most information I see about form submission via Javascript is done with anchor links:

```
<a id="submitButton" href="#">Submit</a>
```

instead of

```
<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
    //do whatever
});
```

I cannot think of any reason that this is the standard practice, but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: I think people do it for styling. Anchors are obviously styled differently and people sometimes want a "button" to look that way, but really submit some form. It's just a lazy way of getting it to look like a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, it was been easier to style links to look like *Not A Standard Button* then rig up form submission with JS (calling the `submit()` method, doing something ajaxy, etc) instead of styling a real button.

There's no reason to beyond the cosmetic, and the lack of graceful degradation gives a good reason not to.

Use a regular submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Many web developers, like myself, just prefer being "different."

There is no right or wrong way to make a submit button, hell, you could make it an image...

It's just a practice, and many times, links look much prettier than buttons.  Pure preference